# Hide Background View from Table View Controller

Tags: swift

I have just added a placeholder label to display text when my table view is empty however I can't figure out how to dismiss the background view once a new cell has been added.

This is how the table view looks once a cell has been added:

[image]

This is the code I am using to display the label:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    println(arrayObject.paymentsArray().count)
    if arrayObject.paymentsArray().count == 0 {
        backgroundLabel.text = "You haven't added any transactions yet. Tap the add button to add a new transaction."
        backgroundLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
        backgroundLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        backgroundLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        backgroundLabel.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundLabel
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        return 0
    } else {
        return arrayObject.paymentsArray().count
    }
}
```

How can I dismiss the background label once a the arrayObject.paymentsArray().count does not equal 0?

EDIT:

I changed the code to this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    println(arrayObject.paymentsArray().count)
    if arrayObject.paymentsArray().count == 0 {
        backgroundLabel.text = "You haven't added any transactions yet. Tap the add button to add a new transaction."
        backgroundLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
        backgroundLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        backgroundLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        backgroundLabel.sizeToFit()
        backgroundLabel.hidden = false

        self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundLabel
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        return 0
    } else {
        backgroundLabel.hidden = true
        return arrayObject.paymentsArray().count
    }
}
```

This now hides the message as intended however the table view has lost the dividing lines in between the cells.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to your background label (say as a property of your viewController) and then set hidden equal to true e.g.

`self.backgroundLabel.hidden = true` on the label in your else clause.else

```
{
    self.backgroundLabel.hidden = true
    return arrayObject.paymentsArray().count
}
```

To get your lines back you need to set the separator style, you set it to **none** - you need single line.

```
{
    self.backgroundLabel.hidden = true
    return arrayObject.paymentsArray().count
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine

}
```

Comment: Ah, of course. I should have noticed that. Another issue I am now having is that the table view has lost the dividing lines in between the cells. I will update my question to include a screenshot of what I mean.